# Compiler reference error due to calling ulldiv.asm for c++ program

Tags: c++, c, assembly

This is a strange error. When I run my code, I had to update the location of ulldiv.asm via

[implementation of unsigned long long division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450394/implementation-of-unsigned-long-long-division/3450502#3450502)

the line in question matched exactly the one used in the link:http://objectmix.com/c/68732-dynamic-memory-allocation-c.html

```
tim = (__time64_t)((nt_time.ft_scalar - EPOCH_BIAS) / 10000000i64);
```

Anyways, the first link gave me the right answer and I relocated ulldiv.asm to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\intel\ulldiv.asm.

Now when I run my code this line gives me trouble

```
double  NOISE_SIGMA = NOISE_DENSITY*sqrt(SYS_CLK_FREQ);
```

the `sqrt` function becomes undefined (?).  The debugger stops and asks me for the location of sqrt.asm.

```
You need to find sqrt.asm to view the source for the current call stack frame
```

This is a similar error that I found in a German website: http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/324725-full

but it doesn't seem to get resolved there.

I don't understand what's going on. If you need more information regarding the code, let me know. Thank you in advance.

If it makes any difference I step through my code using `F11`.

Comment: Just as a side note, I replaced `sqrt` with `pow` in this code `double  NOISE_SIGMA = NOISE_DENSITY*pow(SYS_CLK_FREQ,0.5);` and I got an error that reads `disp_pentium4.inc not found`. I found this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314390/how-to-determine-whether-c-math-uses-sse2 but I'm not sure if the answer to my question is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most of the source files for the Visual C++ libraries are included with the Visual Studio installation, some files are not included.  Notably, the sources for the math library are not included.

The fact that the debugger cannot automatically find ulldiv.asm is a bug; this has been fixed in Visual Studio "14" (I *think* the fix was present in CTP1; I know for sure the fix is present in CTP3 which was released today).